# .net core 3 , MVC , Using 'UseMvcWithDefaultRoute' to configure MVC is not supported while using Endpoint Routing

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to create a simple project based on ASP.NET Core 3.

The MVC template for ASP.NET Core 2.2 has the following line inside the startup-class:

```
app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
```

This line works perfectly in ASP.NET Core 2.2 and routing works, however, in ASP.NET Core 3.0 it doesn't compile and displays the following error

> Using 'UseMvcWithDefaultRoutee' to configure MVC is not supported while using Endpoint Routing.

The question is: "How to configure routing in .net core version 3 for MVC application?"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found the solution, in the following official documentation "[Migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio)":

Thre are 3 approaches:

> 1. Disable endpoint Routing.

```
(add in Startup.cs)

services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
```

> OR
>
> 2. Replace UseMvc or UseSignalR with UseEndpoints.

In my case, the result looked like that

```
  public class Startup
{
    
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
        });
        
    }
}
```

> OR
>
> 3. Use AddControllers() and UseEndpoints()

```
public class Startup
{
    
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
    }

    
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't exist for ASP.NET Core 3 as you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.mvcapplicationbuilderextensions.usemvcwithdefaultroute?view=aspnetcore-2.2&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-3.0) it is only supported until 2.2.

You need to switch to `app.UseMvc();` when registering full MVC pipeline.

For APIs you need to do the following

```cs
app.UseRouting();
app.UseEndpoints(builder => builder.MapControllers());
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, despite the fact that I have already found the solution I much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The most completed free video tutorial of ASP.NET Core is on ASP.NET Core 3, while I'm running ASP.NET Core 6 and this made me run into the below error message.

*An error occurred while starting the application.
InvalidOperationException: Endpoint Routing does not support 'IApplicationBuilder.UseMvc(...)'. To use 'IApplicationBuilder.UseMvc' set 'MvcOptions.EnableEndpointRouting = false' inside 'ConfigureServices(...).*

What I was trying to do is to add MVC to my empty template ASP.NET Core app and  All I did to resolve the error are below lines of code;

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
        });

        //services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            DeveloperExceptionPageOptions developerExceptionPageOptions = new()
            {
                SourceCodeLineCount = 1
            };
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(developerExceptionPageOptions);
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
        });

    }
```

I hope this is helpful to someone out there. Thanks.