# Unable to resolve service for type 'ProfileAdmin' while attempting to activate 'ProfileController'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am working on a ASP.NET Core version 3.0, and I was following a tutorial based on version 2.x and while setting up `Startup.cs`, I was told to setup `UseMvcWithDefaultRoute()`, but since this is not version 2.x, I found this [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58266344/net-core-3-mvc-using-usemvcwithdefaultroute-to-configure-mvc-is-not-suppo) and tried any of those methods. Also, I did setup `AddScoped<>()` in `Startup.cs`. While testing in Postman, I used POST to send json data for `Profile` properties and also tried GET verb to get the list on `http://localhost:5000/Profile`. And both get the same error message on Postman:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'VueJsNetCoreWeb.Models.ProfileAdmin' while attempting to activate 'VueJsNetCoreWeb.Controllers.ProfileController'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
   at lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<CreateActivator>b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Host: localhost:5000
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.24.1
Content-Length: 66
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) //AppSettings
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(o =>
            o.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddScoped<IProfileRepo, ProfileAdmin>();

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
                {
                    builder
                      .AllowAnyHeader()
                      .AllowAnyMethod()
                      .AllowCredentials()
                      .WithOrigins("http://localhost:8080");
                });
            });

            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(opt =>
                {
                    opt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        //IssuerSigningKey = key,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidateIssuer = true
                    };
                });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

            app.UseAuthentication();

            dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

**ProfileAdmin.cs**

```
public interface IProfileRepo
    {
        IEnumerable<Profile> Profiles { get; }
        void AddProfile(Profile profile);
    }

    public class ProfileAdmin : IProfileRepo
    {
        private List<Profile> profiles = new List<Profile>
        {
            new Profile { Id = 1, FirstName = "Omar", LastName = "McMillon", Age = 23 }
        };

        public IEnumerable<Profile> Profiles => profiles;

        private int Id { get; set; }

        public ProfileAdmin()
        {
            profiles = new List<Profile>();
            //Id = 1;
        }

        public List<Profile> GetProfiles() =>
            profiles;

        public Profile GetProfile(int id) =>
            profiles.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);

        public Profile GetProfile(string name) =>
            profiles.FirstOrDefault(p => p.FirstName == name);

        public void AddProfile(Profile profile)
        {
            profile.Id = Id++;
            profiles.Add(profile);
        }

        public void UpdateProfile(Profile profile)
        {
            var currentProfile = GetProfile(profile.Id);

            currentProfile.FirstName = profile.FirstName;
            currentProfile.LastName = profile.LastName;
            currentProfile.Age = profile.Age;
        }

        public void DeleteProfile(int id) =>
            profiles.RemoveAll(p => p.Id == id);
    }
```

**ProfileController.cs**

```
namespace VueJsNetCoreWeb.Controllers
{
    [Route("[controller]")] //name Profile
    [ApiController] //model binding uses json
    public class ProfileController : Controller
    {
        private ProfileAdmin _profileAdmin;

        public ProfileController(ProfileAdmin profileAdmin)
        {
            _profileAdmin = profileAdmin;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public List<Profile> GetProfiles()
        {
            return _profileAdmin.GetProfiles();
        }

        [HttpGet("{name}")]
        public IActionResult GetProfile(string name)
        {
            var profile = _profileAdmin.GetProfile(name);
            if (profile == null)
                return NoContent();
            else
                return Ok(profile);

        }

        [HttpPost] //If no [ApiController], use [FromBody]
        public Profile CreateProfile(Profile profile) 
        {            
            _profileAdmin.AddProfile(profile);

            return profile;
        }

        [HttpPut]
        public IActionResult UpdateProfile(Profile profile)
        {
            _profileAdmin.UpdateProfile(profile);

            return Ok();
        }

        [HttpDelete]
        public IActionResult DeleteProfile(int id)
        {
            _profileAdmin.DeleteProfile(id);
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your controller? Can you show the code?

Comment: We need to see your controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the stack trace, it seems that your controller is receiving a parameter of type `ProfileAdmin` where it should be receiving a `IProfileRepo`, which is what you registered.

Comment: `IProfileRepo` and not `ProfileAdmin` on dependency injection?

Comment: Yes, my answer!